# How can I update a table using MySQL while using search in another table

Tags: mysql

Table panel & panelists have 1 column in common. called user_id where it's an integer for example

table panel:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
user_id         email                   name
---------------------------------------------------------
  5              hello@dummy.com        john
  6              man@city.com           Ronn
  1              fun@dummy.com          Sat
```

table panelists:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
user_id         email_active           
---------------------------------------------------------
  5              1
  6              1
  1              1
```

what I need to do is to change the name where the email include "@dummy.com"
into dummy and to change the email_active to all dummy email in the panel to 2 instead of 1.

I'm not sure how to get this done I've managed to change the name in panelist by searching for the dummy emails using

```
UPDATE panelists SET name = 'dummy' WHERE u_email LIKE '%dummy.com';
```

but I'm not sure how to update the email_active in the panel table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change 2 tables from 1 query like this:

```
UPDATE panelists as a
JOIN panel as s
ON s.uid = a.uid
SET a.pstatus = '2', s.u_name = 'dummy'
WHERE s.u_email LIKE '%dummy.com';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change 2 tables from 1 query like this:

```
UPDATE panel t1, panelists t2
SET t1.email = "dummy", t2.email_active = 2
WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.email like "%@dummy.com";
```

But in case your tables are big (contains many many rows) I'd rather advise you to run 2 separate queries, like this:

```
-- step 1
UPDATE panel SET email = "dummy" WHERE email like "%@dummy.com";

-- step 2
UPDATE panelists t1
JOIN panel t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t2.email = "dummy"
SET email_active = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE panelists 
SET email_active = '2' 
WHERE user_id in (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM panel 
  WHERE email LIKE '%dummy.com'
);
```

This should do the job

You can use a join too like this

```
UPDATE panelists
JOIN panel
ON panelists.user_id = panel.user_id
SET panelists.email_active = '2'
WHERE panel.email LIKE '%dummy.com';
```